# State management of angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx-store

I am new in Angular2. Angular provides various options for managing the state of an application like ngrx/store, angular services etc. if we manage the state of the application using ngrx/store then we require an external library but in case of angular services do not require. What should be used for managing the state of an application? what are the pros and cons of each approach? Is there any recommendation that is provided by the angular community?

Comment: flagged, this is mostly opinion-based

Answer (score 1):

You do not need ngrx/store to implement a redux-store. You can implement one yourself. There are multiple tutorials online showing how to do it in a lightweight way. But ngrx/store is developed and supported by people from google and so it is a mature framework you can trust, which also provides some neat features, like effects for asynchronous events and immutability checks in development.

The main question is whether or not you should use the redux pattern/store in general. This highly depends on your application architecture. For smaller applications it could be too much work, especially if you don't have clear user stories and things might change quickly.But i f you have a big SPA, in general it is recommended to use a central data flow store, e.g. redux. It ensures the dataflow in your application is unidirectional and there are no circular dependencies at important parts of your application, causing weird bugs in the future as your application gets more complex.

Also even in a SPA you have things like UI-Libraries which do not belong in a store. A button prototype being enabled or disabled is something only its component should be aware of. But the same button in usage in the application module should represent a particular functionality being offered or not and that should be represented in redux.

I highly suggest you look at the ngrx-store example app and see the benefits and shortcomings yourself.